# How can i take only particular fields from the model in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi this is My Model(or)Property Field in MVC4

```
 public class LeaveModel : IModel<LeaveModel>
 {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int userId { get; set; }

   public string givenName { get; set; }

   public string shortName { get; set; }

   public string leaveType { get; set; }

   public string leaveDescription { get; set; }

   public string fromDate { get; set; }

   public string toDate { get; set; }

   public int noOfDays { get; set; }

   public string reason { get; set; }

   public string status { get; set; }

   public string statusDescription { get; set; }

   public string createdDate { get; set; }

   public string modifiedDate { get; set; }

   public int leaveTypeId { get; set; }

   public int companyDataId { get; set; }
  }
```

And This is my Controller For Add and Update

```
   [HttpPost]

   public HttpResponseMessage Post(LeaveModel vm)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Ileave.Add(vm));
           return response;
       }
       else
       {
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
       }
   }

  [HttpPut]

   public HttpResponseMessage Put(LeaveModel vm)
   {
       Ileave.Update(vm);
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
```

And This is Database interaction codes

```
    public bool Add(LeaveModel vm)

    {
        try
        {
            vm.createdDate = vm.modifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            IDbCommand cmd = Db.GetCommand("sp_LeaveApply", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            cmd.ParamIn("@LeaveTypeId", vm.leaveTypeId.ToString(), DbType.Int32);
            cmd.ParamIn("@fromDate", vm.fromDate, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@toDate", vm.toDate, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@noOfDays", vm.noOfDays.ToString(), DbType.Int32);
            cmd.ParamIn("@reason", vm.reason, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@createdDate", vm.createdDate, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@modifiedDate", vm.modifiedDate, DbType.String);
            Db.OpenConnection();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Db.CloseConnection();
        }

    }

    public bool Update(LeaveModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            vm.modifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            IDbCommand cmd = Db.GetCommand("sp_LeaveUpdate", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            cmd.ParamIn("@Id", vm.Id.ToString(), DbType.Int32);
            cmd.ParamIn("@leaveTypeId", vm.leaveTypeId.ToString(), DbType.Int32);
            cmd.ParamIn("@fromDate", vm.fromDate, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@toDate", vm.toDate, DbType.String);
            cmd.ParamIn("@noOfDays", vm.noOfDays.ToString(), DbType.Int32);
            cmd.ParamIn("@reason", vm.reason, DbType.String);
            Db.OpenConnection();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Db.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

See the problem here is at the time of adding i need all the fields and the the time of updating i need only certain fields to be updated..for both Add and Update am       refering
``same Model Called (LeaveModel)..so here add is fine but while updating am getting error like DataReaderhas Toomany fields...
I know why this error came but how can i take only certain fields while updating this is the problem..

Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look into using view models instead of coding the view directly against your domain model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you implement a viewmodel class to help you here. For example, for the Update, you could create a new class like so:

```
public class UpdateViewModel
{
    public string givenName { get; set;}
}

public ActionMethod Put()
{
    var original = GetOriginalLeaveModelSomehow();
    var viewModel = new UpdateViewModel();

    viewModel.givenName = original.givenName;
    // The idea is that the viewModel class contains only the fields you want to display to the user.

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionMethod Put(UpdateViewModel viewModel)
{
    var original = GetOriginalLeaveModelSomehow();

    originalMode.givenName = viewModel.givenName;

    Ileave.Update(original);
}
```

I'm not sure if the above code is functionally correct, but the idea of using a viewModel class is the basic point here. It will make life a lot easier for you, since you can be more flexible regards how the data is displayed tot he user; or even which data should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this is to actually have two different view models. One for Adding LeaveModels and one for editing them. Like that the edit model can have only the values you want edited.